# Speed up a long python code that proves to be slow only due to a single block

Tags: c++, python-3.x, performance, numpy

We have a huge volume in space filled with lots of particles (~ 10^8) with known array of masses ('HI_mass'), 3d positions ('HI_position'), and some interesting fraction ('HI_fraction').
There is also some imaginary spheres (~10^3) with different but known array of masses ('mass_data'), positions ('position_data'), and sizes ('radius_data') in this volume.

We want to add up all gas particles (contributing fractionally to gas mass) in each imaginary sphere to come up with a "gas_mass" for each one of the imaginary spheres mentioned above. Once we have this mass for each sphere, then we calculate some quantity called "sigma_HI". If this quantity is above some threshold value, then we keep track of that sphere's individual mass in the form of a dictionary of {id:mass} to later use it for further calculations. Third block is taking forever to run in the context of the entire code which is very long and not included; I only copied that portion of the code that proves to be slow.

```
import numpy as np

enclosing_circles_gas = {}
#info of imaginary spheres where *_data are stored arrays based on some random (otherwise positive integer) ids
for id, position, radius, mass zip(id_data, position_data, radius_data, mass_data):  

    if (mass >= low_mass_cutoff):
        for i in np.where(HI_fraction > 0):                            # HI_fraction is a 1d array
            gas_mass = 0
            if (np.linalg.norm(HI_position[i] - position) <= radius):  # HI_position and position: 3d array of particles and single sphere vector
                gas_mass += HI_mass[i]*HI_fraction[i]                  # HI_mass and HI_fraction are 1d arrays of particles and their fractions
            if (gas_mass/mass >= 1.0e-6):
                enclosing_circles_gas[id] = float('{:.4f}'.format(mass))
```

My question is:
How to use C++ to transform this very slow block in python to speed up the entire code?

Things I have tried:
Changing the nested loop into a list comprehension (but this is still slow)

```
if (mass >= low_mass_cutoff):
        gas_mass = sum( HI_mass[i]*HI_fraction[i] for i in np.where(HI_fraction > 0)[0] if (np.linalg.norm(HI_position[i] - position) <= radius))
        if (gas_mass/mass >= 1.0e-6):
            enclosing_circles_gas[id] = float('{:.4f}'.format(mass))
```

Comment: Using float to string to float conversion in the inner loop sounds like something that could be very slow.

Comment: Try with `round(number[, ndigits])` instead, maybe.

Comment: Looking at the CPython code I see it does the rounding using the same method albeit in C. It still seems like something that would be slow. Do you need correct rounding at 4 decimal places? Maybe you could just truncate the the digits using `fmod()` or such.

Comment: Wix, thank you! This sounds promising. I really do not need this much of decimal places. I just need 2 sig. fig. when put in scientific notation (e.g. 2.3 times 10^(6)). Would you please let me know how to use it in the context of this example? I would appreciate if you post it as an answer. It too late in here and I will try to run your suggestion tomorrow.

Comment: @wilx, I used the first recommendation and it is still running slow. Given that I want the ration to be larger than some very small positive number, I am not sure how to approach the second suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You should find a way to record timing of the individual parts of your loop. But in case it is the string to double to string conversion, what about the following way of truncating digits from the number instead of correct rounding?

```
import math

def trunc_digits(x, digits):
    d = math.log10(abs(x)) - digits
    d = int(math.ceil(d))
    d = math.pow(10, d)
    m = math.fmod(x, d)
    x = x - m
    return x

x = 9.87654321e-6
print (x, "->", trunc_digits(x, 4))
y = 9.87654321e6
print (y, "->", trunc_digits(y, 4))

a = -1.87654321e-6
print (a, "->", trunc_digits(a, 4))
b = -1.87654321e6
print (b, "->", trunc_digits(b, 4))
```

Comment: This should be applied on line 10 of the code as trunc_digits(" ",4) where the entire if condition should be sitting in " ". Right? That's where the distances are calculated and are checked against some maximum value. Just so you know, all my *_data files are indeed some strings from .txt file form which all other parameters are read.

Comment: @Allan As replacement of this bit: `float('{:.4f}'.format(mass))`

Comment: Actually, you want `float` at the end, so I would do `float(trunc_digits(mass, 4))`.

Comment: I tested this as well. No change in the amount of time spent to run the code :(

Comment: Then the time is spent elsewhere. Have you tried running your code under [profiler](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/profile.html)?

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to do it as it is my first time. Thank you for sharing this link. I also opened another question in here to get help on how to do it. Please don't hesitate to let me know in here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58674434/running-a-script-under-a-profiler-when-the-script-itself-is-importing-many-other