# Running a script under a profiler when the script itself is importing many other modules one of which is very slow due to a known function

Tags: python-3.x, performance, module, profiler

Here is the layout of the simulations I am running

```
----main directory
                  -----output (directory)
                  -----halo (directory)
                  -----my_script.py
                  -----settings_centroid.py
                  -----simulation (directory)
                        -----halo_dark (directory)
                        -----halo_analysis (directory)
                        -----gizmo (directory)
                                     -----gizmo_plot.py
                                     .
                                     .
                                     .
```

My `my_script.py` (run under main directory) is:

```
.
.
.
from simulation import gizmo
import settings_centroid
settings_centroid.init()
.
.
.
os.system('> output/{}/Info/{}/{}/redshift_{:.3f}/all_subhalo_properties_gas.txt'.format(settings_centroid.halo_size, settings_centroid.halo_name, settings_centroid.rotation_status, settings_centroid.redshift_z))
.
.
.
gizmo.plot.Image.plot_image(...)
```

My `settings_centroid.py` script is:

```
.
.
.
def init():
    global ....    
.
.
.
```

My `gizmo_plot.py` is:

```
.
.
.
class ImageClass(ut.io.SayClass):

    def plot_image():

        dimen_label = {0: 'x', 1: 'y', 2: 'z'}

        if dimensions_select is None or not len(dimensions_select):
            dimensions_select = dimensions_plot

        if np.isscalar(distances_max):
            distances_max = [distances_max for dimen_i in
                             range(part[species_name]['position'].shape[1])]
        distances_max = np.array(distances_max, dtype=np.float64)

        position_limits = []
        for dimen_i in range(distances_max.shape[0]):
            position_limits.append([-distances_max[dimen_i], distances_max[dimen_i]])
        position_limits = np.array(position_limits)

        if part_indices is None or not len(part_indices):
            part_indices = ut.array.get_arange(part[species_name]['position'].shape[0])

        if property_select:
            part_indices = ut.catalog.get_indices_catalog(
                part[species_name], property_select, part_indices)

        if subsample_factor is not None and subsample_factor > 1:
            part_indices = part_indices[::subsample_factor]

        positions = np.array(part[species_name]['position'][part_indices])
        mass_array = np.array(part[species_name]['mass'][part_indices])                     
        velocity_array = np.array(part[species_name]['velocity'][part_indices])            
        if species_name == 'gas':
            HI_fraction_array = np.array(part[species_name]['hydrogen.neutral.fraction'])   

        weights = None
        if weight_name:
            weights = part[species_name].prop(weight_name, part_indices)

        center_position = ut.particle.parse_property(part, 'center_position', center_position)

        if center_position is not None and len(center_position):
            # re-orient to input center
            positions -= center_position
            positions *= part.snapshot['scalefactor']

            if rotation is not None:
                # rotate image
                if rotation is True:
                    # rotate according to principal axes
                    if (len(part[species_name].host_rotation_tensors) and
                            len(part[species_name].host_rotation_tensors[0])):
                        # rotate to align with stored principal axes
                        rotation_tensor = part[species_name].host_rotation_tensors[0]
                    else:
                        # compute principal axes using all particles originally within image limits
                        masks = (positions[:, dimensions_select[0]] <= distances_max[0])
                        for dimen_i in dimensions_select:
                            masks *= (
                                (positions[:, dimen_i] >= -distances_max[dimen_i]) *
                                (positions[:, dimen_i] <= distances_max[dimen_i])
                            )
                        rotation_tensor = ut.coordinate.get_principal_axes(
                            positions[masks], weights[masks])[0]
                elif len(rotation):
                    # use input rotation vectors
                    rotation_tensor = np.asarray(rotation)
                    if (np.ndim(rotation_tensor) != 2 or
                            rotation_tensor.shape[0] != positions.shape[1] or
                            rotation_tensor.shape[1] != positions.shape[1]):
                        raise ValueError('wrong shape for rotation = {}'.format(rotation))
                else:
                    raise ValueError('cannot parse rotation = {}'.format(rotation))

                positions = ut.coordinate.get_coordinates_rotated(positions, rotation_tensor)

            # keep only particles within distance limits and with speeds less than 500km/sec compared to the parent halo.
            masks1 = (positions[:, dimensions_select[0]] <= distances_max[0])   #part[species_name]['position'][part_indices]
            for dimen_i in dimensions_select:
                masks2 = (np.abs(part[species_name]['velocity'][:, dimen_i] - settings_centroid.HCV[dimen_i]) < 500)
                masks_part = masks1 * masks2
                masks_part *= (
                              (positions[:, dimen_i] >= -distances_max[dimen_i]) *
                              (positions[:, dimen_i] <= distances_max[dimen_i])
                              )

            positions = positions[masks_part]
            mass_array = mass_array[masks_part]
            velocity_array = velocity_array[masks_part]
            if species_name == 'gas':
                HI_fraction_array = HI_fraction_array[masks_part]
            else:
                HI_fraction_array = None


            if weights is not None:
                weights = weights[masks_part]
        else:
            raise ValueError('need to input center position')

        if distance_bin_width is not None and distance_bin_width > 0:
            position_bin_number = int(
                np.round(2 * np.max(distances_max[dimensions_plot]) / distance_bin_width))
        elif distance_bin_number is not None and distance_bin_number > 0:
            position_bin_number = 2 * distance_bin_number
        else:
            raise ValueError('need to input either distance bin width or bin number')

        #radiuss_array, positions_array, masss_array = [], [], []
        if hal is not None:
            # compile halos
            if hal_indices is None or not len(hal_indices):
                hal_indices = ut.array.get_arange(hal['mass.200m'])

            if 0 not in hal_indices:
                hal_indices = np.concatenate([[0], hal_indices])

            hal_positions = np.array(hal[hal_position_kind][hal_indices])
            if center_position is not None and len(center_position):
                hal_positions -= center_position
            hal_positions *= hal.snapshot['scalefactor']
            hal_radiuss = hal[hal_radius_kind][hal_indices]
            hal_masss = hal['mass.200m'][hal_indices]                                   
            hal_ids = hal['id'][hal_indices]                                            
            hal_distances = np.linalg.norm(hal['host.distance'], axis=1)[hal_indices]   
            hal_star_masss = hal['star.mass'][hal_indices]                      
            hal_star_sizes = hal['star.radius.90'][hal_indices]                 

            # initialize masks

            masks = (hal_positions[:, dimensions_select[0]] <= distances_max[0])
            for dimen_i in dimensions_select:
                masks *= (
                    (hal_positions[:, dimen_i] >= -distances_max[dimen_i]) *
                    (hal_positions[:, dimen_i] <= distances_max[dimen_i])
                )

            hal_radiuss = hal_radiuss[masks]
            hal_positions = hal_positions[masks]
            hal_masss = hal_masss[masks]                         
            hal_ids = hal_ids[masks]                             
            hal_distances = hal_distances[masks]            
            hal_star_masss = hal_star_masss[masks]                
            hal_star_sizes = hal_star_sizes[masks]               

            halo_ids = 'output/{}/Info/{}/halo_catalog_{:.3f}/halo_ids.txt'.format(settings_centroid.halo_size, settings_centroid.halo_name, settings_centroid.redshift_z)
            halo_masses = 'output/{}/Info/{}/halo_catalog_{:.3f}/halo_masses.txt'.format(settings_centroid.halo_size, settings_centroid.halo_name, settings_centroid.redshift_z)
            halo_radii = 'output/{}/Info/{}/halo_catalog_{:.3f}/halo_radii.txt'.format(settings_centroid.halo_size, settings_centroid.halo_name, settings_centroid.redshift_z)
            halo_positions = 'output/{}/Info/{}/halo_catalog_{:.3f}/halo_positions.txt'.format(settings_centroid.halo_size, settings_centroid.halo_name, settings_centroid.redshift_z)
            halo_distances = 'output/{}/Info/{}/halo_catalog_{:.3f}/halo_distances.txt'.format(settings_centroid.halo_size, settings_centroid.halo_name, settings_centroid.redshift_z)
            halo_star_masss = 'output/{}/Info/{}/halo_catalog_{:.3f}/halo_star_masses.txt'.format(settings_centroid.halo_size, settings_centroid.halo_name, settings_centroid.redshift_z)
            halo_star_sizes = 'output/{}/Info/{}/halo_catalog_{:.3f}/halo_star_sizes.txt'.format(settings_centroid.halo_size, settings_centroid.halo_name, settings_centroid.redshift_z)

            np.savetxt(halo_ids, hal_ids, fmt='%.0f')
            np.savetxt(halo_masses, hal_masss, fmt='%.3e')
            np.savetxt(halo_radii, hal_radiuss, fmt='%.3e')
            np.savetxt(halo_positions, hal_positions, fmt='%.3e')
            np.savetxt(halo_distances, hal_distances, fmt='%.3e')
            np.savetxt(halo_star_masss, hal_star_masss, fmt='%.3e')
            np.savetxt(halo_star_sizes, hal_star_sizes, fmt='%.3e')

    def get_histogram(...):
        if '3d' in image_kind:
            # calculate maximum local density along projected dimension
            hist_valuess, (hist_xs, hist_ys, hist_zs) = np.histogramdd(positions, position_bin_number, position_limits, weights=weights, normed=False,)

            # convert to 3-d density
            hist_valuess /= (np.diff(hist_xs)[0] * np.diff(hist_ys)[0] * np.diff(hist_zs)[0])

        else:
            # project along single dimension
            hist_valuess, hist_xs, hist_ys = np.histogram2d(positions[:, dimensions_plot[0]], positions[:, dimensions_plot[1]], position_bin_number, position_limits[dimensions_plot], weights=weights, normed=False,)

            # convert to surface density
            hist_valuess /= np.diff(hist_xs)[0] * np.diff(hist_ys)[0]

            # convert to number density
           if use_column_units:
               hist_valuess *= ut.basic.constant.hydrogen_per_sun * ut.basic.constant.kpc_per_cm ** 2
               lls_number = np.sum((hist_valuess > 1e17) * (hist_valuess < 2e20))
               dla_number = np.sum(hist_valuess > 2e20)

               LLS, DLA = lls_number, dla_number
               self.say('Number of grids:      LLS = {:.0f}, \t DLA = {:.0f}'.format(lls_number, dla_number))


               # Counting absorber grid number in each subhalo
               if return_halo_info:
                   subhalos_gas = 'output/{}/Info/{}/{}/redshift_{:.3f}/all_subhalo_properties_gas.txt'.format(settings_centroid.halo_size, settings_centroid.halo_name, settings_centroid.rotation_status, settings_centroid.redshift_z)

                   hal_positions_data = np.loadtxt(r'output/{}/Info/{}/halo_catalog_{:.3f}/halo_positions.txt'.format(settings_centroid.halo_size, settings_centroid.halo_name, settings_centroid.redshift_z))
                   hal_radiuss_data = np.loadtxt(r'output/{}/Info/{}/halo_catalog_{:.3f}/halo_radii.txt'.format(settings_centroid.halo_size, settings_centroid.halo_name, settings_centroid.redshift_z))
                   hal_masss_data = np.loadtxt(r'output/{}/Info/{}/halo_catalog_{:.3f}/halo_masses.txt'.format(settings_centroid.halo_size, settings_centroid.halo_name, settings_centroid.redshift_z))
                   hal_ids_data = np.loadtxt(r'output/{}/Info/{}/halo_catalog_{:.3f}/halo_ids.txt'.format(settings_centroid.halo_size, settings_centroid.halo_name, settings_centroid.redshift_z))
                   hal_distances_data = np.loadtxt(r'output/{}/Info/{}/halo_catalog_{:.3f}/halo_distances.txt'.format(settings_centroid.halo_size, settings_centroid.halo_name, settings_centroid.redshift_z))

                   totals_gas = {}
                   sub_circle_catalog_gas  = []
                   enclosing_circles_gas = {}
                   for hal_id, hal_position, hal_radius, hal_mass, hal_distance in zip(hal_ids_data, hal_positions_data, hal_radiuss_data, hal_masss_data, hal_distances_data): 
                       if ((hal_distance <= settings_centroid.distance_max) and (log10(hal_mass) >= settings_centroid.low_mass_cutoff)):
                           hal_gas_mass = sum(settings_centroid.part_HI_mass[i]*settings_centroid.part_HI_fraction[i] for i in np.where(settings_centroid.part_HI_fraction > 0)[0] if (np.linalg.norm(settings_centroid.part_HI_position[i] - hal_position) * settings_centroid.scale_factor <= hal_radius))

                           if (hal_gas_mass/hal_mass > 1.0e-8):
                               enclosing_circles_gas[hal_id] = float(settings_centroid.trunc_digits(log10(hal_mass), 4))

                   # choose all subhalos' IDs enclosing the DLA pixel
                   enclosing_circles = list(enclosing_circles_gas.keys())
                   sub_circle_catalog_gas += [(enclosing_circles_gas[i], 1) for i in enclosing_circles]

                   # add up all special grids in each sub-circle when looping over all grids
                   for key, value in sub_circle_catalog_gas:
                       totals_gas[key] = totals_gas.get(key, 0) + value
                   totals_gas = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(totals_gas.items()))
                   totals_gas = list(totals_gas.items())

                   with open(subhalos_gas, "a") as smallest_local_subhalos:
                       print('{}'.format(totals_gas), file=smallest_local_subhalos)
                       smallest_local_subhalos.close()

                   os.system('> output/{}/Info/{}/halo_catalog_{:.3f}/halo_positions.txt'.format(settings_centroid.halo_size, settings_centroid.halo_name, settings_centroid.redshift_z))
                   os.system('> output/{}/Info/{}/halo_catalog_{:.3f}/halo_radii.txt'.format(settings_centroid.halo_size, settings_centroid.halo_name, settings_centroid.redshift_z)) 
                   os.system('> output/{}/Info/{}/halo_catalog_{:.3f}/halo_masses.txt'.format(settings_centroid.halo_size, settings_centroid.halo_name, settings_centroid.redshift_z)) 
                   os.system('> output/{}/Info/{}/halo_catalog_{:.3f}/halo_ids.txt'.format(settings_centroid.halo_size, settings_centroid.halo_name, settings_centroid.redshift_z))  
                   os.system('> output/{}/Info/{}/halo_catalog_{:.3f}/halo_distances.txt'.format(settings_centroid.halo_size, settings_centroid.halo_name, settings_centroid.redshift_z))


       masks = (hist_valuess > 0)
       self.say('histogram min, med, max = {:.3e}, {:.3e}, {:.3e}'.format(hist_valuess[masks].min(), np.median(hist_valuess[masks]), hist_valuess[masks].max()))
       hist_limits = np.array([hist_valuess[masks].min(), hist_valuess[masks].max()])
       return  hist_valuess, hist_xs, hist_ys, hist_limits
.
.
.
```

It seems that while running `my_script.py`, it is taking forever to produce results. With trial and error it seems that the slow part is happening inside *if...if* nested loop under the function called `get_histogram()` inside `gizmo_plot.py` module. But, I need to run `my_script.py` under a profiler to exactly find the slow line. Could you please help me how this can be done by outputting the profile in a different file? In particular, how to locate exactly the slow line of the funciton?

---

Output of the procedure suggested by Wilx below are:

```
my_script.prof% sort cumulative
my_script.prof% stats 5
Mon Nov  4 14:32:25 2019    my_script.prof

         76741270081 function calls (76741240862 primitive calls) in 107707.564 seconds

   Ordered by: cumulative time
   List reduced from 4432 to 5 due to restriction <5>

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    814/1    0.373    0.000 107707.595 107707.595 {built-in method builtins.exec}
        1    0.348    0.348 107707.331 107707.331 my_script.py:1(<module>)
        2  312.439  156.219 105178.281 52589.140 gizmo_plot.py:220(plot_image)
        2    5.966    2.983 104209.307 52104.654 gizmo_plot.py:658(get_histogram)
       69    0.001    0.000 104168.283 1509.685 {built-in method builtins.sum}
```

---

Second Check:

```
my_script.prof% sort time
my_script.prof% stats 10
Mon Nov  4 14:32:25 2019    my_script.prof

         76741270081 function calls (76741240862 primitive calls) in 107707.564 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time
   List reduced from 4432 to 10 due to restriction <10>

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
9592513999 41813.829    0.000 80076.700    0.000 linalg.py:2203(norm)
       69 24091.619  349.154 104168.282 1509.685 gizmo_plot.py:726(<genexpr>)
9592514405 9783.770    0.000 9783.770    0.000 {built-in method numpy.core.multiarray.dot}
9592514634 8158.522    0.000 11181.488    0.000 numeric.py:433(asarray)
9592514062 7065.503    0.000 7065.503    0.000 {method 'ravel' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
9592513998 5393.512    0.000 7708.295    0.000 linalg.py:113(isComplexType)
19185030173/19185030020 4839.445    0.000 4839.831    0.000 {built-in method builtins.issubclass}
9592517050 3069.880    0.000 3072.494    0.000 {built-in method numpy.core.multiarray.array}
     11/3  605.531   55.048  605.532  201.844 gizmo_io.py:190(prop)
      376  530.257    1.410  530.655    1.411 dataset.py:634(read_direct)
```

Comment: Can't you precompute the result of `np.where(settings_centroid.part_HI_fraction > 0)[0]` outside the loop? But I don't think this help much. It seems to me you have so much data that your single threaded Python approach is simply not good enough. Have you considered rewriting this in something compiled and parallelizable? It seems to me the loop iterations are independent and you should be able to carve chunks and process them in parallel.

Comment: I will try the first suggestion. However, I have never done parallelization and I need yet to learn it.

Comment: I tested that and no change seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the profiler like `python3 -m cProfile -o my_script.prof my_script.py`. This should create a `my_script.prof` after your script finishes. You can than load that `.prof` file with `python3 -m pstats my_script.prof`.

Comment: Hi Wilx, Here is what I have with the second command so far. Welcome to the profile statistics browser. my_script.prof%. How long should I wait for it to finish?

Comment: Regardless of how many times I enter "help", this is the only thing it says afterwards: Documented Commands (type help <topic>):
EOF  add  callees  callers  help  quit  read  reverse  sort  stats  strip

my_script.prof%

Comment: Ok, I figured that out. I printed the output in the body of the question. I hope that will help you to see why the mentioned function is taking to much time to run.

Comment: I wish I had more info on exactly which line of this function is problematic.

Comment: I think I know which line is now taking time. Would you please check my work in the addition of the post to see if it's right? If so, then would this help you to rewrite the line to speed up the code in the original post?